# Convert a typescript enum into an array of enums

Tags: typescript

I have an enum

```
export enum A{
   X = 'x',
   Y = 'y',
   Z = 'z'
}
```

I want this to be converted to

```
[A.X, A.Y, A.Z]
```

Type of the array is A[]. How to do this?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100718/typescript-enum-to-object-array

Comment: @SudhirOjha, your comment lead me to the right answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use **Object.keys** to get the keys of the enum and use them to get all the values.

It would look something like this.

```js
let arr: A[] = Object.keys(A).map(k => A[k])
```

You can see it working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20X%20%3D%20'x'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Y%20%3D%20'y'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Z%20%3D%20'z'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20Object.keys(A).map(k%20%3D%3E%20A%5Bk%5D%20as%20string)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(arr)%3B).

Comment: I want to retain the type as enum. I am editing your answer accordingly

Comment: I believe you can use `Object.values(A)` as well, to avoid unnecessary mapping. Enum is compiled to just an object, thats why both `keys` and `values` methods work here.

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof A'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof A'.`

Comment: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Object.values** to get value of enum

```
enum A {
  X = 'x',
  Y = 'y',
  Z = 'z'
}
let arr = Object.values(A)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: ([Matt Leonowicz assumed so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554208/convert-a-typescript-enum-into-an-array-of-enums#comment102808662_52554378))