# get enum value by ordinal index typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have this enum:

```
enum defaultShaderType {
  VERTEX_SHADER = 23,
  FRAGMENT_SHADER = 57
}
```

Is there a direct way to access the numeric values by ordinal index of an enum in typescript?
What I want is for example:

```
const value1 = defaultShaderType[0]; //23
const value2 = defaultShaderType[1]; //57
```

When I try it that I obtain undefined.
In my case I want the values in a for loop, so I would like to get the values for the number of elements in the enum. I know there are many workarounds and that can achieve that with other data structures, but can a typescript enum be used this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript enum to object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100718/typescript-enum-to-object-array)

Comment: it does. If you post it I will accept it. Thanks