# Avoid any type getting enum values in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to loop through an enum type to populate some options in a react component.
Find below the enum and the function that retunrns the keys and values from it.

```
export enum ProyectType {
  time, 
  hits, 
  value, 
  results
}

function projectTypeValues() {
  const values = Object.keys(ProyectType).filter(k => typeof ProyectType[k as any] === "number"); // ["time", "hits", "value", "results"]
  const keys = values.map(k => ProyectType[k as any]); // [0, 1, 2, 3]
}
```

I dont like the `any` type in the `ProyectType[k as any]` so I tried:

```
type EnumIndex = number | string;
ProyectType[k as EnumIndex]
```

But I obtain: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`

I thought the indexer could be of type number or string, as the the `Object.Keys` is an array of the 8 elements: `["0","1","2","3","time","hits","value","results"]` but neither of both works.

How can the `any` type be removed in this situation if the enum types are already known?

Comment: Can't you use any of these solutions instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100718/typescript-enum-to-object-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is that the [type signature for `Object.keys(obj)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f74f9cac1344f6c88078c65d89a4d496bd5a8525/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L261) has the return type as `string[]` and not something like `Array<keyof typeof obj>`.

This is intentional: object types in TypeScript are *open* and not *closed*; they must some set of known properties, but they *might* have *additional* properties.  See the Q/A pair ["Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript) for more details.

So the compiler sees you trying to index into `ProyectType` with an arbitrary `string`, and isn't happy about it.  In cases where you just don't care about the possibility of extra keys, or if you happen to know what the keys will be, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler what it can't figure out.

For example, you could do this:

```
type ProyectTypeKeys = Array<keyof typeof ProyectType | number>;
// type ProyectTypeKeys = (number | "time" | "hits" | "value" | "results")[]

const values = (Object.keys(ProyectType) as ProyectTypeKeys).
    filter((k): k is keyof typeof ProyectType =>
        typeof ProyectType[k] === "number");
// const values: ("time" | "hits" | "value" | "results")[]

const keys = values.map(k => ProyectType[k]);
// const keys: ProyectType[]
```

Here I am defining `ProyectTypeKeys` as an array type whose elements are either the known string keys of the enum object or `number`... this is what you expect to see, and why you're doing the `filter()` step.

Similarly, I have annotated the `filter()` callback as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) so that the compiler uses [a call signature for `filter()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f74f9cac1344f6c88078c65d89a4d496bd5a8525/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1367) that narrows the type of the output of `filter()` from the full array type `ProyectTypeKeys` to just the type that comes out: `keyof typeof ProyectType`, a.k.a., `"time" | "hits" | "value" | "results"`.

After this, the inferred type of `keys` is `ProyectType[]`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwApQgT2AYxgBUcxg4BvAKDlrhgEtVgAaGugCwZgGc264ANwCGAG2St2tKMB7JRvKgF8qqqgDNkiQgwiI4YbACsCxUsABqYiTwAUASkqqBMc5mx5CJMgGlgOHjgAXjgAQSgoYRwAHgBrfwh1enNE91xTb3IAHzgUVAAjYCgAPgBuKTgAekrksjTPM19-QJDbPMKoOByAIkZmbq64bq5eAZ6RcWAxoZk5BR5u+wBtAF1nOnw9HngJm2C4WwB5fJNCADp4gNssdK9zR2FAm4bMvwD7M4qBdQYFIttbLF7AAuOCxOAMQKXVKuMipZ4ZNxBYpfAR0WHAeEeRFkJaxFbBIIhbrtIqLcoCapwTaIbZCayyUG2XpMKaDYbcBbs3ZsnqzeSjZZrCo0umXFr0yY8M6oYRgQHBYr1HHAPErewUuhU0XwcWghF3XFrJRAA)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's really weird, it seems to happen just in some functions.

take a look in this approach:

```
const keys = [];
const values = [];
for(const index in ProyectType){
   //typescript infers string to index const  but here there is no error
  typeof ProyectType[index] === "number" ? values.push(index) : keys.push(index)
 
}
```

One possible solution to use the way that you wrote your code without error is using the unknown type + number.

```
const values = Object.keys(ProyectType).filter(k => typeof ProyectType[k as unknown as number] === "number"); // ["time", "hits", "value", "results"]
```

Comment: I try to avoid any and unknow as much as possible and the accepted answer approach seems more correct (`(k): k is keyof typeof ProyectType`). That was what I was looking for, however yours is also a useful snippet, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Type Assertions

This is an elegant and alternative way ;) Considering that `enum`s can contain only `string` and `number` types and your action *is intentional*, you can use **type assertions** to obtain your values and keys. Type Casting (or assertion) is a way to say to the compiler that you know what are you doing. You can find more info at [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

In your case, the function should be like this:

```
function projectTypeValues() {
  const values = Object.values(ProyectType)
                .filter((val) => isNaN(val as number));
  const keys = Object.keys(ProyectType)
              .filter(key => !isNaN(key as unknown as number))
              .map(key => +key);
}
```

I used `key as unknown as number` because in this case our keys are `string`. Then I mapped them to convert strings to numbers as you wrote.

Comment: I try to avoid `any` and `unknow` as much as possible, however that was a useful snippet, thanks for your answer