# Typescript Convert Enum to Constant Class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I convert an Enum to a Constant Class like this, in Typescript? Currently using React Typescript, with functional components .
This question is slightly different: [TypeScript enum to object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100718/typescript-enum-to-object-array)

```
export enum ProductStatus {
  Draft = 1,
  Review = 2,
  Approved = 3,
  Rejected = 4,
  Billed = 5,
  Collected = 6,
  Unpayable = 7,
  WorkInProgress = 8,
  ReadyToReview = 9,
  NeedsRevision = 10,
  Failed = 11,
}

export const ProductStatus = {
  Draft: 1,
  Review: 2,
  Approved: 3,
  Rejected: 4,
  Billed: 5,
  Collected: 6,
  Unpayable: 7,
  WorkInProgress: 8,
  ReadyToReview: 9,
  NeedsRevision: 10,
  Failed: 11,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop throught the keys and use ethe `reduce` function

```
  const newConst = React.useMemo(() => {
    return Object.keys(ProductStatus).reduce((acc, key) => {
      if (isNaN(Number(key))) {
        acc[key] = ProductStatus[key];
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }, []);

  console.log(newConst );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ivfxqw?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Object.values` to get the values from the `enum` and convert them to an object using `reduce`.

```
const ProductStatusObject = Object.values(ProductStatus)
  .filter((v): v is keyof typeof ProductStatus => typeof v !== "number")
  .reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c] = ProductStatus[c]
    return p
  }, {} as Record<keyof typeof ProductStatus, number>)

ProductStatusObject
// ^? Record<"Draft" | "Review" | "Approved" | ..., number>
```

As you may know, enums contain a mapping in both directions. We need to filter out the values which are not of type `string` to only get the keys of the `enum`. The `filter` callback also needs a type predicate to indicate to TypeScript that the resulting array only contains values of type `keyof typeof ProductStatus`.

The `reduce` method takes the elements of the array and assigns them as keys to an object using the corresponding enum value. I typed the object as `Record<keyof typeof ProductStatus, number>` to get a useful return type.

```
console.log(ProductStatusObject)

/*
{
  "Draft": 1,
  "Review": 2,
  "Approved": 3,
  "Rejected": 4,
  "Billed": 5,
  "Collected": 6,
  "Unpayable": 7,
  "WorkInProgress": 8,
  "ReadyToReview": 9,
  "NeedsRevision": 10,
  "Failed": 11
} 
*/
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewCZgMYBcDK6CG6wDOUA3gFBRQAicOAZulALxQCMANOVAErABuAlsADuTKACYOFAIIAHGYl7AkogMyTuwAFbAMS0QBZ1AIX4AbU3uYBWdQGEE5nektQAbOoCqIGTgCeOACMLUQB2dQB1BDgAawBJEHgEAHM4YAIiZgAOdR4cJF8AFQQeAWFRAE51ADlgJQIS-gJ+BBBRFgAGdQAxHDMXFnZSAF9SUlQWggZElAxsPEIAeQDtDFEllfQAOl4cUzA0gApptCxcfAIASk5N2jNnOAOD3guALiheKEaoaOBfBFooOhfDJgP9YIgZqd5hkAHyA4GggEfACEjGYACJwBAAsA4OirhRNqkZsBHjI2FBUBcmHCyBQKDIANqoAC6omOszOhGZLM4FFS+DgrRknCGFOIQygOCIPHGcCQAB4fn8AUCQWCOVDzhSsTi4DCrqRNXNzusnKQAPQWqAAPQA-Bo5Yr0dQ6Oh0VAAD5QdENYQe73o2TyBCKJABqCbKM6yB6mGjcYgAgOYCbUzJI4Qk4mxbLJwXIA)

Comment: Or just `Object.fromEntries` with `Object.entries` and filtering for numbers: https://tsplay.dev/ND2b1W