# Angular - how to work with enums and Record

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular, but I'm stuck with enums.

I created test app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mmh4tc
(app/test component)

But it does not work as I expected.

1. test.component.html. line 45
   why does not work: {{ FileType2LabelMapping[element.type] }}
   (Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Record<FileTypesEnum, string>'.)
   element.type is Enum type
   the getTypeLabel() method contains the same code, so why it could not be used directly in the template?

When click on edit button, I set itemToEdit object and allow to edit values.

2. Why mat-select has no initial value? Item.key should be enum type, shouldn't it?
3. When I select value from combo, why type of selected value is changed to string?
   (there is eg. "1" instead of 1)

Thanks a lot for any help or explanation, how it should work.
T.

I tried to find out solution here on stack overflow, but with no success.
I expect that I will understand what i did wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. element.type is Enum type the getTypeLabel() method contains the same code, so why it could not be used directly in the template?

Believe this is similar to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16273), in which the `element` is `any` type as default behavior. This same goes for `element.type`. Meanwhile the indexer/accessor for `FileType2LabelMapping` requires the value either in `string`, `FileTypesEnum` (refer to the screenshot below). Thus, this will throw the error as mentioned for Q1 and you can solve it via `getTypeLabel(element.type)` method as you explicitly define/provide the value type.

> 2. Why mat-select has no initial value? Item.key should be enum type, shouldn't it?
> 3. When I select value from combo, why type of selected value is changed to string? (there is eg. "1" instead of 1)

The reason why the select element is not bound with data is due to conflicting types between the key from `FileType2LabelMapping` (`number`) and `itemToEdit.type` (`FileTypeEnum`).

As you see in the screenshot below,

[image]

The `K` will be set/initialized with number value of `FileTypeEnum` in string type but not the `FileTypeEnum` type.

You can verify by iterating `FileType2LabelMapping`, the `item.key` will be printed as a number.

```
<div
    *ngFor="let item of FileType2LabelMapping | keyvalue"
  >
  {{ item.key == 0 }} // Will give error: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'string' and 'number' have no overlap.
  {{ item.key == '0' }} // This works correctly
</div>
```

For setting the `<select>` element with a (selected) value, I would propose implementing an array of objects that hold the value and label name to be displayed (`fileTypes`).

```
fileTypes = Object.values(FileTypesEnum)
  .filter((x) => isNaN(Number(x)))
  .map((x: any) => ({
    value: FileTypesEnum[x],
    name: FileType2LabelMapping[
      FileTypesEnum[x as keyof typeof FileTypesEnum]
    ],
}));
```

Reference: [TypeScript enum to object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100718/typescript-enum-to-object-array)

```
<mat-select name="type" required [(ngModel)]="itemToEdit.type">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let item of fileTypes"
    [value]="item.value"
  >
    {{ item.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

With this implementation, the selected value `itemToEdit.type` will remain as a `number` type instead of `string` when displaying as JSON.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-myxgxg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html)